# Docker for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: docker, windows-server-2012-r2

I am unable to find a compatible docker version which supports Windows 2012 R2. Upon some research, I found out that Windows 2012 does not support docker.

How can I run docker in a Windows 2012 R2 server? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only option available for you would be to setup a virtual machine inside Windows Server 2012 and run a Docker Supported OS on it.